# White lines around the logo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, white

today I'm here to ask you how to export better on Illustrator!
I made a text logo, I was going on Photoshop to add a background and I saw these lines:

[image: Did I do something wrong with Illustrato?]

Did I do something wrong with Illustrator or Photoshop?
Help me!

Comment: You'll have to provide more info if you want a clear answer. How did you import it in Photoshop?

Comment: I only drag and dropped it from the folder to inside Photoshop

Comment: Is the white object behind the black strokes same size as the black one by any chance? Conflation hits again.

Comment: No the White text is the 1st and behind I put a copy of it (black) with an increased outstroke

Comment: You say you dragged and dropped it from a folder into Photoshop, but you did not say what format it is in? Is it an AI, a PNG, or what?

Comment: I saved the project from Illustrator as a PNG and the drag and dropped into Photoshop

Comment: Try dragging the actual .ai file directly into Photoshop and NOT saving it out as another filetype

Comment: The underlying problem is that when Illustrator saved your image, the border got antialiased assuming a *white* background, rather than transparent. If you insist on saving as a PNG, check its export settings. But as said, it ought to be possible to use the original AI in Photoshop as well.

Comment: If I will not export them as PNG, how can I export them to avoid this types of issues?

Comment: The problem is not that it's a PNG, the problem is that you exported the wrong kind of PNG. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PNG, then check you exported as PNG24, and not PNG8.  If you export as PNG8 from Illustrator, the image will be in Indexed colour, and that is what is causing your problem.

[image]

Of course, you can also avoid this problem completely by placing the AI file directly in Photoshop.

Answer (score 4):

**Stop** *exporting* anything from Illustrator for Photoshop. There is **no need** to export *anything*.

Either copy from Illustrator, and then paste into Photoshop (as a Smart Object), or **save** your .ai file, then use `File > Place` within Photoshop to place the .ai file into Photoshop.

Your issue is because you are *unnecessarily* exporting the vector content in Illustrator as raster images. You can use the vector content in Photoshop. By exporting Illustrator artwork to a raster format (png) you are actually *degrading* the quality.

Comment: Thank you very much! When I've done, how should I export it from photoshop if PNG will degrade the quality?

Comment: If you need a PNG then exporting from Photoshop as a PNG is fine. My point was you *do not* want to alter formats when **moving between Illustrator and Photoshop**. Leave it vector whenever possible.